# How to get private key from 12-word backup and public key?

Tags: wallet-recovery, bip32-hd-wallets, copay, bip44

It turned out, to one 12-word backup, billion address could belong. It is not always sure app like Copay found all the address contains money.

Is it a way to infer the private key from 12-word backup and wallet ID / (public key).

It seems the only way to restore my balance is based on private key.